# Chrome Debugger extension in VS Code will not display a html file

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome-extension

I started to learn angular and created a simple project in Visual Studio and it ran fine there. It is only one html file and a separate JS file. I decided to try Visual Studio Code as this looks like a better environment to code in for front end work.
But for the life of me I cannot get the Chrome debugger to display the page.

Here is the current launch.json (tried several changes to url and webroot to no luck):

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost",
            "url": "http://localhost:9222/index.html",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}"
        },
        {
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "attach",
            "name": "Attach to Chrome",
            "port": 9222,
            "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}"
        }
    ]
}
```

I can get chrome to launch and connect but I get a completely blank page. I can then go to Localhost/json which gives me this:

```
[ {
   "description": "",
   "id": "2c0aed08-5bf3-4186-9ad6-9af1bc9e500c",
   "title": "localhost:9222/index.html",
   "type": "page",
   "url": "http://localhost:9222/json"
}, {
   "description": "",
   "devtoolsFrontendUrl": "/devtools/inspector.html?ws=localhost:9222/devtools/page/ccfbea86-ec75-434e-9ae0-749eba4cbf2b",
   "id": "ccfbea86-ec75-434e-9ae0-749eba4cbf2b",
   "title": "Chrome Media Router",
   "type": "background_page",
   "url": "chrome-extension://pkedcjkdefgpdelpbcmbmeomcjbeemfm/_generated_background_page.html",
   "webSocketDebuggerUrl": "ws://localhost:9222/devtools/page/ccfbea86-ec75-434e-9ae0-749eba4cbf2b"
} ]
```

I have no clue at this point what to try or really how to debug or look at what might be causing this. Any help or direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure this is the correct answer. But changing the launch.json to include the file itself worked. I can now debug and view my pager in the browser window. Also turning on the diagnosticLogging allowed me to see the how it was doing some of the mapping.

```
{
    "name": "Launch Chrome",
    "type": "chrome",
    "request": "launch",
    "url": "http://localhost:9222/",
    "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}\\",
    "file": "${workspaceRoot}/index.html",
    "diagnosticLogging": true
}
```